# Making an HTTP POST request swift with session

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I try do POST request to backend server and use this for base session inside of a class "ServiceUtils" in objective - c

```
(AFHTTPSessionManager *)baseSessionManager {

        if (httpSessionManager) {
            return httpSessionManager;
        }

        httpSessionManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        httpSessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        // User agent for iOS app.
        NSString *userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxxx Mobile iOS/%@ (%@ - %@ v%@)", [Utils appVersionWithBuild], [[UIDevice currentDevice] model], [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName], [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]];

        [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

        // Mobile auth 
        User *user = [User getUserWithContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
        NSString *mobileAuth = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@--givemymoneybackdude", user.token] sha1];
        [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:mobileAuth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Mobile-Auth"];

        // Authorization
        NSString *authorization = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:X", user.token] stringBase64];
        [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authorization] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        // Locale
        if (user.locale) {
            [httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:user.locale forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
        }

        return httpSessionManager;
    }
```

Here is my code to try make POST request in swift 2.3

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "xxxxxxxx") {
            let session = ServicesUtils.baseSessionManager()
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let jsonObject = ["token" : "Token String", "refresh_token" : "refresh_token String","expires_in" : "expires_in String", "user_id" : "uber_uuid", "token_type" : "Bearer"]


            request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: [])

            session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                guard
                 error == nil &&
                        (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200
                    else {
                        print((response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? "no status code")
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no error description")
                        return
                }
                }.resume()
```

After try this i get this error :

> Request failed: unauthorized (401)

I checked the header and it is ok but this problem is occurring. Can someone tell me why it's happening? And how could I pass inside a **jsonObject** a dictionary called "Integration" containing the values in it

Comment: why sending token in json data? It should be passed as a header value .This is not a solution though but a suggestion.

Comment: @TusharSharma  due to is coming from an integration by Uber, after integration was done I pick up the information and send it to the backend

Comment: So you also getting any authentication token or something?

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes

Comment: are you sending that token as an header?

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes, basically i want to send token in jsonObject but after receive this i don't know how to pass this information into a dictionary called "Integration".

Answer (score 0):

This Code will help You…And using Alamofire.

```
    Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .post, parameters: (parametersDictionary as NSDictionary) as? Parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

        if(response.result.error == nil){

            if((response.response?.statusCode)! < 500){

                if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {

                        let dict = JSON as! NSDictionary
                        let status :Bool = dict["status"] as! Bool

                        if(status){
                            success(dict)
                        }else{
                            failure(dict["message"] as! String)
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    failure("Something went wrong please try again")
                }
            }else{
                 failure("Something went wrong please try again")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope the following Link will may help you: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire